# Compile code to a specific C/C++ standard

Tags: c++, c, g++, clang++

I have tried googling this but all I get is results on how to compile a basic program.
Is it possible to compile code to a specific C++ standard using Clang++ and G++ by specifying that code should be compiled to say, C89, C99, C++98, etc?

Comment: Yes (sort of, anyway). See the [`-std=XXX`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options) command line argument. The "sort of" is that you get gcc's best approximation of the specified standard, which isn't always exactly correct.

Comment: g++ (and gcc) accepts the `-std` command line parameter to specify which standard to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the -std flag.  For example, to compile to C99, use `-std=c99`

The documentation for it is [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html)

Answer (score 5):

Use the `-std` flag like this:

```
g++ -std=c++98 -o myprog myprog.cpp -lfoo
```

[Here is a man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/g++) with plenty of GCC/G++ options, including this one.